# How do I check a type is of a specific template?

Tags: c++, std

I would like to use the standard library to check that a type is a specific template. I'm not sure if I'm using the right terms here. This is what I want:

```
// this is pseudo-code
template <typename X>
struct MyStruct {};

int main()
{
  bool check1 = std::is_of_template<MyStruct, bool>::value; // false
  bool check2 = std::is_of_template<MyStruct, std::vector<int>>::value; // false
  bool check3 = std::is_of_template<MyStruct, MyStruct<int>>::value; // true
}
```

I know that `is_of_template` does not exist and that this  syntax is not even legal, but I hope it illustrates what I'm after. Does the Standard Library provide some functionality that would help me to achieve something like this?

Comment: No, the standard library won't help you here, but see the duplicate question.

Comment: @Brian thanks, not sure how I missed that!